# setContentView and findViewById

Tags: android

After reading some related posts I already know that I have to explicitly call to setContenView before trying to find by id an element into an Activity-View-Hierarchy. I've created an Activity with an inflated view and all works fine. The problem is when I try to set another view to this activity by using the next xml and code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:background="#B12A6D"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_purple_500"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    >

<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:rowCount="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:context=".GridXMLActivity"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >

         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/my_bnt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_new_game"
            android:contentDescription="@string/text"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            />
</GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}


....

protected void method_triggered_from_UI_thread() {

  // Inflate other layout...
  View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.my_layout, null) ;
  setContentView(view);
  ImageView btn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_bnt);
  // btn is null...

}
```

I've tried other slight variations:

```
View mainView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, (ViewGroup) mainView, false)  ;
setContentView(view);
ImageView btn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_bnt);
```

And I always get btn == null. What am I doing wrong?

Thx

Comment: `ImageView btn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_bnt);` for first case

Comment: Does my_layout has thr button with Id my_bnt?

Comment: What is `mainView` ?

Comment: Try it using `new LinearLayout(mainActivity)` instead of `(ViewGroup) mainView` as second parameter

Comment: Can you post your total java code?

Comment: mainView = mainActivity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);

Comment: new LinearLayout(mainActivity) instead of (ViewGroup) mainView does not work

Comment: And yes, my_layout has the id my_btn

Comment: So then is `R.id.my_bnt` a typo? Are you *sure* that you're using the right ID, because your code looks fine.

Comment: I'm sure that's the right ID

Comment: post xml also i can see clearly what the problem is if you share xml i can solve your problem.

Comment: I tested your code with the exact same layout and bnt wasn't null. What device did you test it on?

Comment: I've checked all the children views into view after setContentView and they all have their mID == -1

Comment: where do you call `method_triggered_from_UI_thread`?

Comment: Did you try the way i suggest  ?

Comment: are you sure the method 'method_triggered_from_UI_thread' is calling and it is in Main thread

Comment: Where you called "method_triggered_from_UI_thread()" function? I have executed. If you called properly, it will works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't realize the id my_bnt exist but only in one of the existing layouts (not in layout-land nor in layout-xlarge). 
Thx for your help

Answer (score 2):

You could try LayoutInflater.

```
View inflatedView = LayoutoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout, null);
setContentView(inflatedView);
```

Happy codings

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait the end of the replacement. Try this:

```
View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.my_layout, null);
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {          
     @Override          
     public void onGlobalLayout() {              
        // continue the initialization from here:
        btn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_bnt);
        //...

        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);        
     }      
}); 
setContentView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure btn and bnt are the same?

I'd suggest using Fragments [Google dev Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

However if you want to do it like this, give your 'outer' Layout in main_activity.xml a certain id, say rootView. Then call this:

```
protected void methodTriggeredFromUiThread(){
    LinearLayout rootView = findViewById(R.id.rootView);
    View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.my_layout, null) ;
    rootView.removeAllViews();
    rootView.addView(view);
    view.findViewById(R.id.my_bnt); 
}
```

To use fragments create a class implementing Fragment for every type of view your activity might have. Your main_activity will only hold a FrameLayout (besides persistent headers, tabs, whatever). Since the button is a view that is inside the fragment which is inside the main activity calling findViewById(R.id.btn) anywhere in the main activity will yield the button, as long as the fragment is loaded.

**somewhere in activity_main.xml:**

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  </FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loadFragment(new DemoFragment());
    }
    protected void loadFragment(Fragment fragmentToLoad) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, fragmentToLoad);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

**DemoFragment.java**

```
public class DemoFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout,
                container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know the standard way to create fragments into activities, but in this case I'm trying to use only one activity and change the GUI elements dynamically (by exchanging layouts)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, in your **R.layout.activity_main add some ViewGroup** (FrameLayout) and than in method_triggered_from_UI_thread() add inflated view to that container:

```
protected void method_triggered_from_UI_thread() {

// Inflate other layout...
  View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.my_layout, null);

// add new view to the container view in activity layout
 (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container).addView(view);

ImageView btn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_bnt);

}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
You can't assign a view,and do findviewbyid to an activity outside oncreate, an it just won't work. 
you need to rearrange your code in 
//declare image as global variable
ImageView btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   Bundle extraArgs = getIntent().getExtras();
String layoutname=extraArgs.get("LayoutName");
if(layoutname="main")
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
else 

  setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
  btn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_bnt);

}



protected void method_triggered_from_UI_thread()
{
//Call the main activity again with bundle giving view 
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("LayoutName", "UR_LAYOUT_NAME");
startActivity(intent);/// or use startactivityforresult,

//access btn here
}
```

Comment: The first part of your answer is wrong, you can use `findViewById` method everywhere in your activity class and you can also call `setContentView` outside `onCreatePart` method.